# Displaying a "Loading" message in Java Swing with HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'm having trouble getting a "Loading" message to show up while my program is fetching an URL. I tried using several different methods such as `Thread`, `SwingWorker`, and `SwingUtilities`, but the "Loading" message always shows up after it fetches the webpage. How can I get it to display "Loading" before fetching the webpage?

```
public static void get(String url)
{
    content.add(new JLabel("Loading..."));
    content.repaint();

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // load webpage
        }  
    });
}
```

Comment: Basically, you're doing it the wrong way around. The GUI should be updated inside invokeLater() or invokeAndWait().

Comment: So am I suppose to call invokeLater() twice? Once for "Loading" and once for the actual content?

Comment: No. Do not put your long-running code inside invokeLater. It should be done in a background worker thread. If get() is called in such a thread then put the code there. Otherwise you can use something like SwingWorker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but the "Loading" message always shows up after it fetches the webpage.

then your code is blocking the EDT so the GUI can't repaint itself.

> I tried using several different methods such as ... SwingUtilities,

The code you posted using invokeLater() is wrong because you are still executing the long running task on the EDT.

> I tried using several different methods such as Thread, SwingWorker, -

Those are the proper approaches. The long running task should exectute in the Thread or the `doInBackground()` method of your Swing worker.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.